# Бот на pyrogram не запускается

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, pyrogram

Такая проблема.
Попробовал запустить эхо бота для телеграм.
Установил все нужные модули, а результат не меняется.

> $ python main.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line
> 789, in get
> value = d[option]   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/collections/**init**.py",
> line 941, in **getitem**
> return self.**missing**(key)            # support subclasses that define **missing**   File
> "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/collections/**init**.py",
> line 933, in **missing**
> raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'api_id'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/userbot/main.py", line 10, in
>
> app.run()   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py",
> line 61, in run
> self.start()   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py",
> line 56, in async_to_sync_wrap
> return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py",
> line 642, in run_until_complete
> return future.result()   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py",
> line 53, in start
> is_authorized = await self.connect()   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/auth/connect.py",
> line 38, in connect
> self.load_config()   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py",
> line 617, in load_config
> self.api_id = parser.getint("pyrogram", "api_id")   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line
> 818, in getint
> return self._get_conv(section, option, int, raw=raw, vars=vars,   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/configparser.py",
> line 808, in _get_conv
> return self._get(section, conv, option, raw=raw, vars=vars,   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line
> 803, in _get
> return conv(self.get(section, option, **kwargs))   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line
> 792, in get
> raise NoOptionError(option, section) configparser.NoOptionError: No option 'api_id' in section: 'pyrogram'

Код:

```python
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client("my_account")

# Эхо
@app.on_message(filters.me)
def echo (Client, message):
    message.reply_text(message.text)

app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

https://my.telegram.org/auth?to=apps - тут создаем api "API development tools" и копируем хэш и id

Создаем config.ini и пишем

[pyrogram]

api_hash =api_hash

api_id =api_id

Answer (score 1):

нужно писать api_id и api_hash как параметры при вызове функции Client

```
app = Client("my_account", api_id="ваш api_id", api_hash="ваш api_hash")

# Эхо
@app.on_message(filters.me)
def echo (Client, message):
    message.reply_text(message.text)

app.run()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]